# In joins if specific column is null than in return resulting query does not retun a whole row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to get records from multiple tables. If "im.path" column is null in the db against the specific id, then in result whole row is skipped.

I want that if image does not exit against the specific id, then in result it shows the row with a image path column empty.

My query is below.

```
select distinct p.person_id as p_id,i.current_status,p.*, im.path from invitation i 
join person p on i.person_id=p.person_id
join user u on p.person_id=u.person_id
join image im on u.user_id=im.entity_id
where sender_account_id=40 or i.person_id=40 and invitation_category_id=1
```

In this case if im.path column is empty, then whole record is skipped, that is what I do not want

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use an outer join (LEFT, right or full outer depending on situation.)

Comment: thanks dear i got my result by using left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct p.person_id as p_id, i.current_status, p.*, im.path 
FROM invitation i 
INNER JOIN person p on i.person_id=p.person_id
INNER JOIN user u 
 on p.person_id=u.person_id
LEFT join image im 
  on u.user_id=im.entity_id
WHERE (sender_account_id=40 
   or i.person_id=40)
 and invitation_category_id=1
```

I'm also suspicious of not having ()'s around the OR statement here; so I added them.
also without knowing where sender and invitation_category_ID reside, they may limit the results inappropriatly from the left join.  So what table are sender_account and invitation_category_ID in?

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ is a great link explaining join types.